# Azure Saml toolkit integration with Azure web app

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I am trying to implement Azure saml sso with my angular web app.

I have deployed angular web app in azure and created a enterprise application(Azure saml toolkit).

I have assigned users in first step.

I couldn't find useful links or steps to configure Azure saml toolkit and not sure how to specify
Sign-in url,Assertion url and redirect url for my site in toolkit.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the instructions [here](https://samltoolkit.azurewebsites.net/)?

All the details are in the SAML configuration pages when configuring SSO for the enterprise application.

Comment: These steps are not clear. I doesn't say how to integrate my app to saml azure toolkit. Where do i get sign in url,redirect url for my site

Comment: You don't. "This is a sample SAML application created for Azure AD customers to test the SSO integration". In others words, it is the application. You can't integrate your application with it.